# Is there any way to abbreviate dired-header?

Tags: dired

```
/home/farhad/phpPlay:
 controllers
 index.php

/home/farhad/phpPlay/controllers:
 index.php
```

In a `dired-mode` buffer like above I want to replace `/home/farhad/` with `~`. Is it possible?

Comment: It's because `dired-readin` does `(expand-file-name dirname)`. And also because `dired-noselect` sets `dirname` to `(file-truename dirname)` if `find-file-visit-truename` is non-`nil`. I think you would need to advise or tinker a bit, to prevent the expansion.